# Unable to install <software name> : you do not have permission to install software

Tags: package-management, software-installation, permissions, 22.04

I get the following error: "you do not have permission to install software".

[image]

Comment: We can assume the question is: How do I get permission to install software. So please elaborate: Is this a company computer, where you don't have superuser (sudo) access? If this is the case, talk to your IT department. If it's your own computer, you should have sudo access.

Comment: Its a personal computer.

Comment: Are you using a user account that has admin permission (`sudo`)?

Comment: @user535733 Yes , sudo works in the terminal.

Comment: There should have been a password pop-up. Did you cancel or close it? Or did you enter your password?

Comment: @user535733 Nothing popups after clicking on install, only the no permission banner appears.

Comment: Are you able to install the software using the Terminal? `sudo apt install google-chrome-stable`

Comment: @user535733 Yes, only the gui software manager is not working for installation.